# Why does npm install a bunch of .cmd files on my project root folder?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Why does npm install a bunch of files and .cmd files on my root folder?
If I remove the files and run npm install again, those .cmd files will reappear. Why doesn't npm download those files and stored it into node_modules folder?

When I clone the repo in another computer, it doesn't create those .cmd files. Both computer are running windows 10.

After several testing, I found out that if I delete package-lock.json file first then only perform npm install, then those .cmd won't appear, but then now the project fails to start.

[image: screenshot of project root folder]

[image: screenshot of package.json file]

Comment: Having the same issue on a project and we're basically diff'ing the before and after npm install to see what files were dumped, then removing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is only reproducible when using prefix then it is very possible that it is a bug in npm (there is a similar issue in [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm) that I was going to fix).

There is no workaround to this at the moment. There are no configs to set the bin location. So you should avoid using the prefix config until npm fixes the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me - the fix on Windows was to go to `c:\Users\{username}\.npmrc` and remove the prefix.

Comment: What kind of prefix you remove from there?

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis open the .npmrc file and there would be a line saying Prefix={your_folder_path}. Just leave that line like Prefix= and you should be good.

Comment: I removed the Prefix line completely because it was set to Prefix= and files were being dumping. Once I deleted the line from the file it no longer outputted all the files!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved when I run `npm install` directly in the folder instead of using `npm install --prefix`.

<sup>This was extracted from the question post and moved here on the author's behalf.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by resetting node js config

[Here](https://newbedev.com/how-to-restore-reset-npm-configuration-to-default-values) is doc how to do it