# NPM install in Visual Studio Code adds .cmd, .ps1 files to my VSCode explorer

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm-install

When I run npm install in my javascript project in VSCode, It adds .cmd, .ps1 and files without extensions to the VSCode explorer window. This is annoying and floods my explorer window. Is there a setting that is leading to this and How can I stop these files from displaying and cluttering my project

I tried adding the .ps1 and .cmd file extensions in the Files:Exclude settings. But the files without an extension still appear.

Comment: It would help to know what you're installing - perhaps add your `package.json` to the question?

Comment: Hi @Andy. Thanks for the response. I did some research and found a solution that fixed my issue here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653324/why-does-npm-install-a-bunch-of-cmd-files-on-my-project-root-folder)